# File manager that can queue transfers and copy actual files later

Tags: gratis, windows-7, file-management

I have a whole lot of data on multiple platforms, multiple drives, etc. that either have many photos or large videos that I want to reorganize but would take forever to copy to multiple locations.

I plan to copy everything to a NAS at one location.

I was wondering if anyone knows a software package (preferably free) that has a GUI where you can move virtual folders and files around quickly and then later run a process to "copy those files".

Comment: Did you look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_copying_software ?

Comment: Can try with Teracopy which can make your needs i think.

Answer (score 1):

[QCopy](http://www.flit.com.au/web/content/files/qcopy) is a freeware tool for Windows that "allows you to queue up any number of files, from any number of locations, and copy them *to a specific destination* on the fly. You can pause and resume at any time, skip files or save the queue for transfer later."

Another possibility is [MiniCopier](http://www.adriancourreges.com/projects/minicopier/), a multi-platform graphical copy manager published under GNU GPL. Copying will begin immediately once a destination has been added, however, the file transfer can be paused and then additional operations added.  The program allows selection of distinct destinations for each transfer operation, but the transfer queue cannot be saved.

Comment: Anther excellent file manager which can pause it Total Commander (http://ghisler.com/) and an excellent "fast copier" is TeraCopy (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeraCopy), but it is not clear whether the OP will accept that "start/pause/resume later" is the same as "queue".

Comment: I recommend SpeedCommander it also queues operations like moves, copies and deletions.